# Ubuntu 16.04 Excessive disk i/o

Tags: 16.04, cinnamon

Since installing 16.04 on my laptop my disk seems to be constantly busy I ran `iotop` and I can see a process `cinnamon --replace` running frequently. Could this be the cause of my problems ? If so any suggestions ?

NOTE : this is Cinnamon 3 ...

EDIT : I uninstalled Cinnamon and there is still more than expected disk activity. I certainly did not have this with 14.04. I think there is an issue with Ubunutu 16.04. But hard to diagnose what it is ...

Comment: You are using Ubuntu? Because Cinnamon is Linux Mint's DE.

Comment: Yes I installed Cinnamon on top of Ubuntu, I can't get to grips with Unity

Comment: Ah. This wouldn't help solve your problem, but did you try XFCE? It's very customizable.

Comment: I'll give it a bash if I can't get Cinnamon to work, tks ... just been using the same desktop for years ...

Comment: Doing a quick search, it looks like you are one of many people who are having similar issues since Cinnamon 2.17.  There are numerous bug reports, and I don't see any fixes. :(

Comment: Thanks @ThatGuy ... I tried XFCE, but still getting the disk activity so wonder if it might be something else ...

Comment: I can think of two possible issues, either graphics drivers (Cinnamon is heavy on effects), or hardware acceleration maybe?  What's the largest consumer of CPU/RAM in `iotop`?

Comment: There is a process called `cinnamon --replace`